# Show "Page expired" on back button - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, cache-expiration

I have a form that is sent via POST method and it display's a blade view after submitting.
Many users hit the browser back button and resubmit the form. How can i show a "Page expired" when the user hits the back button?

I want this so that the user must follow the process of filling the form from scratch. I say from scratch because submitting the form is the 3rd step. Before this i have 2 other steps.

When the user hits the back button on the 3rd step i want to show him a page expired or maybe redirect him to the 1st step.

Comment: In JS `history.replaceState()` to replace the history with a "expired page"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a session in 2rd step.and when user redirect to 3rd step you should expire this session and in 2rd step check session is expired or not by ajax and if session is expired you can show a message like this "Page expired"